# Differences between 'instrument' vs 'instrumentality', when used in the same sentence?

Tags: difference, legalese

[Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=U5CgAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT10&ots=cgTRNLfAjh&dq=how%20to%20read%20cases%20in%20law%20school&pg=PT22#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20read%20cases%20in%20law%20school&f=false): (Page number unprinted), Chapter 2, *Acing Your First Year of Law School* ..., by Shana Connell Noyes, Henry S. Noyes

> *Delair v. McAdoo*, Supreme Court of Pennsylvania, Nov 23 1936.
>   [Author:] KEPHART, Chief Justice.
>
> > ... Any ordinary individual, whether a car owner or not, 
> >     knows that when a tire is worn through to the fabric, its further use is 
> >     dangerous and it should be removed. When worn through several plies, it 
> >     is very dangerous for further use. All drivers must be held to a knowledge 
> >     of these facts. An owner or operator cannot escape simply because he says 
> >     he does not know. He must know. The hazard is too great to permit cars in 
> >     this condition to be on the highway. It does not require opinion evidence to 
> >     demonstrate that a trigger pulled on a loaded gun makes the gun a 
> >     dangerous instrument when pointed at an individual, nor could one escape 
> >     liability by saying he did not know it was dangerous. The use of a tire 
> >     worn through to the fabric presents a similar situation. The rule must be 
> >     rigid if millions are to drive these **[instrumentalities](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/instrumentality)** which in a fraction of a second may become **instruments** of destruction to life and property. There 
> >     is no series of accidents more destructive or more terrifying in the use of 
> >     automobiles than those which come from "blow-outs."

Hereafter, I singularise the bold nouns above, because I ask about their differences in general.
1. What would change if I reversed **instrumentality** with **instrument**  above?

2. What of using only **instrumentality** twice?

3. What of using only **instrument** twice?

Comment: It's just an example of the clunky language which results from a lawyer trying to write like a journalist. It's best to leave it aside and move on.

Comment: Like a bad journalist.  "dangerous for further use"?

Comment: I think the usage is defensible. The cars are *instrumentalities* (defined by OED's sense 2 *with pl. That which serves or is employed for some purpose or end; a means, an agency*) with the *explicitly-acknowledged* "purpose or end" of getting people from place to place. Using two different word forms highlights the contrast between that "purpose by design" and the "accidental side-effect" encapsulated in the cliched *instruments of destruction* (with its overtones of being unwitting tools under the control of some higher entity such as Fate or the Devil).

Comment: I was commenting on the writing style. But the author is trying to make a little parable to show the legal difference between *instrument* and *instrumentality*. Not the clearest parable I've ever heard.

Comment: It appears the book is quoting a 1936 ruling from the Pennsylvania Supreme Court. "Dangerous for further use" appears to be a legalism going back to the 1800s. In everyday English, one would expect "Too dangerous for further use".

Comment: @TRomano Thanks for the elucidation. Yes it is. I had forgotten to cite this but have done so now.

Comment: It's not clunky. It scholarly legal writing.

Answer (score 1):

Instrumentality simply means that it can become (or be used as) as instrument.  An instrumentality is that which can be wielded as an instrument, i.e. perceived in terms of its capacity to be wielded.

Not all instruments can be held in the hand, of course; some can be abstractions, such as a legal entity, which can be "wielded" by another legal entity.  A parent corporation can "wield" a subsidiary as if it were an "instrument".